# How to make font size responsive using vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In [vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com) they have helper classes for typography.

for example, `.display-4` goods for `h1`. [here the full list](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/typography#typography).

When I choose display-1 for some element, In all resolutions the class gets the same font size (34px).

I was expecting to:

- `.display-4` will have font size of 34px in screen wide of 1024px.
- `.display-4` will have font size of 18px in screen wide of 300px.

According to this I have two questions, why is that? and how to make my font size elements be responsive using vuetify?

Comment: Why do you think they would be responsive? There is not a single media query attached to those classes.  If you want them to be responsive, you need to write your own media queries.

Answer (score 6):

**Update**

**Vuetify version 1.5**

Take a look at display helpers [example](https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/display#examples) to see how to use a class when hitting a breakpoint. That being said, you can use **dynamic class binding** and [**breakpoint object**](https://v15.vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/breakpoints#breakpoint-object) in Vuetify.

Example:
`:class="{'subheading': $vuetify.breakpoint. smAndDown, 'display-2': $vuetify.breakpoint. mdAndUp}"`

**Vuetify version 2**

[breakpoint object](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/breakpoints#breakpoint-object)

[Display](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/display#display)

Answer (score 5):

My solution changes font-sizes globally in the `variables.scss` file:

This is assuming you're using Vuetify 2 and @vue/cli-service 3.11 or later.

**Step 1:**

In `src/scss/` create `_emptyfile.sass` and `_font-size-overrides.scss`.

In the `_emptyfile.sass` you can add this comment:

```
// empty file to workaround this issue: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/7795
```

**Step 2:**

In the `_font-size-overrides.scss` file:

```
/**
 * define font-sizes with css custom properties.
 * you can change the values of these properties in a media query
*/

:root {
    --headings-size-h1: 28px;
    --headings-size-h2: 22px;
    @media #{map-get($display-breakpoints, 'lg-and-up')} {
        --headings-size-h1: 32px;
        --headings-size-h2: 26px;
    }
}
```

**Step 3:**

In the `variables.scss` file (where you override the Vuetify variables):

```
/**
 * Override Vuetify variables as you normally would
 * NOTE: remember to provide a fallback for browsers that don't support Custom Properties
 * In my case, I've used the mobile font-sizes as a fallback

*/

$headings: (
    'h1': (
        'size': var(--headings-size-h1, 28px),
    ),
    'h2': (
        'size': var(--headings-size-h2, 22px),
    )
);
```

**Step 3:**

In the `vue.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                prependData: `@import "@/scss/_emptyfile.sass"` // empty file to workaround this issue: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/7795
            },
            scss: {
                prependData: `@import "@/scss/variables.scss"; @import "@/scss/_font-size-overrides.scss";`,
            }
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: Worked.  is there a simpler option using Vuetify or other?

Answer (score 3):

font-sizes globally in the **variables.scss** file

```
html {
    font-size: 90%;
    @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
        font-size: 94%;
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
        font-size: 98%;
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
        font-size: 100%;
    }
}
```