# Globally change font size in Vuetify based on viewport?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, viewport

This is a duplicate of this post:

[Change font size in Vuetify based on viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52086822/change-font-size-in-vuetify-based-on-viewport)

However, I'm looking for help to see if there is a way to do this on a global level so that all components are affected - as opposed to having to do it on each individual component as I use them?

Comment: simply use rem everywhere and change html font size with media queries

Comment: It will affect in globally if you do it in ```<style></style>```. Not in ```<style scoped></style>```

Comment: @oshell That's a clever solution, thanks!

My only concern is that I'm trying to match a design so not all font-sizes will scale at the same rate as each other... but nonetheless I think your solution may help for 90% of the cases.

Comment: This is actually an exact duplicate of this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56603008/how-to-make-font-size-responsive-using-vuetify/60528495?noredirect=1#comment107080701_60528495